# Database is locked in SQlite when using php artisan migrate:refresh

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I am learning Laravel and I have encountered a problem when I want to refresh a migration.

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

I am using SQlite and below is the error I am getting

```html
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked (SQL: drop table if ex
  ists "generate_pins")
```

The problem seems like it comes from the SQlite having locked the database, How do I unlock the database? After I have unlocked, can I lock it again?

I am learning both Laravel and SQlite and any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it looks like some process is using the database and it is locking the file or more likely you've made some kind of error in your code causing too many queries at the same time.

Please provide more detailed information. What OS, Laravel version, your database configuration (*.env* and *config/database.php*), your *migration files* and their contents, database structure (run `slqite3 path/to/database.sqlite` then  `.tables`), and the contents of your *migrations table* (while still in sqlite run `select * from migrations;`).

Comment: I have the same problem presently, my sqlite3 uses database.sqlite as its data store. I've used `fuser database/database.sqlite` to check the programs using the file and it turns out that it's the same laravel application. This started when I came back to the app after leaving it for a while. The same test always ran without a hitch before I came back to it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. Delete `database.sqlite`
2. `php artisan optimize:clear`
3. `php artisan migrate`